# passing file name as argument

Tags: c, file, dynamic, filenames

```
char fname[256];
printf("Enter file name\n");
scanf("%123s",fname);
strcat(fname,".txt");

FILE *inputf;
inputf=fopen(fname,"w");

if (inputf!=NULL)
    printf("found");
else
    printf("not found");
```

Mow the problem is that no matter what file name i enter i get a non 
null pointer.can any one explain why??

Comment: In what environment do you run this code? Your own computer? A shared terminal, possibly a school pc? Ssh access to somewhere else? If you are running linux, what is the output of "ls -l"? Because it seems you lack the permissions for writing to filesystem.

Comment: You code compiles fine on my system. It creates file if doesn't exit with "w" parameter. You have to check what @junjanes suggested.

Comment: what if i lack permission?? can i throw an appropriate error message?

Comment: Is this a linux box? If so `#include <unistd.h>` and query `access(fname, W_OK)`. It returns 0 if file is writable. Different non-zero return values mean different problems. Google "unistd access" for more info.

Answer (score 3):

fopen(filename,"w") will create a new file.  Therefore, if you're entering a legal file name and have proper file system permissions, it should succeed.

If you're trying to open an existing file, use:

```
fopen(filename, "r")
```

(Notice the "r" mode, instead of "w".)

Comment: @samir - Then the parameter should be "r+". This specifies an already existing file to both read and write. The file must exist.

Comment: no i mean that if i want to create a completely new text file on the hard disk???

Comment: "w" creates a new file whether there is an existing one or not.  Any existing file by that name is discarded.  ...back to your question in your original post: why do you want a NULL pointer? [edited to change "r" to "w"]

Comment: @dappawit - No, for "r" the file must exist. Though the link I give isn't standard, you can check- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: Yes, my mistake... I meant "w".

Comment: @dappawit i cant find the new file which gets created

Comment: The file should be created in the directory where you execute your program.  (Unless you supply a filename containing directories, such as foo/bar/file.txt, then the file would be created in that directory if the directory exists)

Answer (score 0):

Not this:
`char fname[256]; 
printf("Enter file name\n"); 
scanf("%123s",fname); 
strcat(fname,".txt"); F
FILE *inputf; inputf=fopen(fname,"w");  // <--!!!
if (inputf!=NULL) printf("found"); 
else printf("not found");`

but this instead:

char fname[256]; 
FILE *inputf;

inputf=fopen(fname,"w");
printf("Enter file name\n");

// you know that you can't ever, EVER use scanf( ) so
// remove this time bomb and use something else
scanf("%123s",fname);

strcat(fname,".txt"); 
inputf=fopen(fname,"w"); 
if (inputf!=NULL) {
  printf("found"); 
}
else {
  printf("not found");
}

Now, what pointer was not NULL? You could not have compiled the code as you had it, so how do you know what was or was not NULL?

--pete

Comment: inputf should be null if file was not found on the system..so it is not NULL even if  i  enter an invalid file name.

Comment: and could you tell me better option than scanf??

Comment: @Pete: I must be missing something.  Why shouldn't his original code compile?

Comment: http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGLL_enUS384US384&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=elsfph&xhr=t&q=scanf+harmful&cp=13&qe=c2NhbmYgaGFybWZ1bA&qesig=kbma3TLQD2oEC5Ci_AZMtA&pkc=AFgZ2tlW-5Q2C1_538q6Lw16JQzag0CBAOadBLPbkGuOvGFa9O7wNWyexSjWiVQdzy4N5h6ycfbTPRmpJMHwIFc8rmTk7tJ0PA&pf=p&sclient=psy&rlz=1B3GGLL_enUS384US384&site=webhp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=scanf+harmful&pbx=1&bav=on.1,or.&fp=18e4c0cc530c3619

Comment: dappawit, it can't compile because of the attempt to allocate FILE *inputf in the middle of executable code. It has to be at the top, before any code.

Comment: samir, take a look here:  http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGLL_enUS384US384&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=elsfph&xhr=t&q=scanf+harmful&cp=13&qe=c2NhbmYgaGFybWZ1bA&qesig=kbma3TLQD2oEC5Ci_AZMtA&pkc=AFgZ2tlW-5Q2C1_538q6Lw16JQzag0CBAOadBLPbkGuOvGFa9O7wNWyexSjWiVQdzy4N5h6ycfbTPRmpJMHwIFc8rmTk7tJ0PA&pf=p&sclient=psy&rlz=1B3GGLL_enUS384US384&site=webhp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=scanf+harmful&pbx=1&bav=on.1,or.&fp=18e4c0cc530c3619   Then figure out what to use in place of scanf( ). Perhaps fread( ) on stdin would work -- give it a shot.

Comment: samir, as for inputf being non-NULL: it will be non_NULL if the file was opened for writing successfully, which I guess it was. The file does not have to exist already if mode is "w". Have a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output

Comment: @Pete: Most C compilers now allow declarations to be mixed with your executable code.

Comment: I just compiled that exact code with gcc 4.5.2.  All I did was wrap it in a main() function.  (to clarify--I used the code given in the original question posted by samir rai.)

Comment: You DID? Well, I'll be damned. I apologize for my mistaken comments. Thanks, dappawit, I had no idea!

Comment: OK, now I finally get it: the prog was compiled as C++, where I was thinking it was C. Nice catch, dappawit. I'm glad to know this.

Comment: I'm wrong again! I must be living in some other century. gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 compiles it as a C prog. Yours truly, Rip van Winkle.